# Dash data table with large amount data

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Hi I'm trying to make a dashboard by using Dash.

However, I'm going through a problem that it is too slow to load the data I have.

I want to load the data on the table more fast so, I thought that segmenting the dataframe and load the separated data when I click button I define like pagination
but it looks a little bit complex for me.

If there is any method to make through this problem, please let me know.

Thank you for your input!

I wrote the code like this.

```
from dash import Dash, dash_table
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

app = Dash(__name__)

df_viewer = pd.DataFrame(
    OrderedDict([
        (name, col_data * 30) for (name, col_data) in df_viewer.items()
        ])
)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    columns=[{'id': i, 'name': i} for i in df.columns],
    virtualization=True,
    fixed_rows={'headers': True},
    style_cell={'minWidth': 80, 'width': 80, 'maxWidth': 80},
    style_table={'height': 380}  # default is 500
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```